# Recommended way to prevent naming pollution by helper classes in C#?

Tags: c#, scope, namespaces, naming-conventions, naming

I often come across the pattern that I have a main class and several smaller helper classes or structs.

I'd like to keep the names of thoses structs as clean as possible. So when I have a class that's called `CarFinder` that heavily makes use of some special Key object that is only (or mainly) used internally, I'd like to call that object `Key` instead of `CarFinderKey`.

Everything to remove all the extra *fuzz* that distracts me from when I try to understand the class while reading it.

Of course I don't want to pollute the rest of the code with a small helper class that is called `Key` - it most likely will clash and confuse.

In a perfect world I would have liked to have a keyword like `internal to this namespace`, but as that does not exist that leaves me the following options that I can think of:

---

1. Use `internal` and put the class in a different project.

**Advantage:** Perfect encapsulation.

**Disadvantage:** A lot of organisational overhead and unnecessary complicated dependencies.

*Note: I'm not talking about really large self contained systems that undoubtedly deserve their own assembly.*

---

2. Put it in a different child namespace, like `CarFinding.Internal`

**Advantage:** Easy to implement.

**Disadvantage:** Still can pollute when the namespace is accidently imported.

---

3. Put the helper class as a child class within `CarFinder`.

**Advantage** Doesn't pollute internally and can even be promoted as a public helper struct that is exposed to the outer world with `CarFinder.Key`

**Disadvantage** Have to put the helper class within the same file, or encapsulate it in an external file with `public partial class` around it. The first one makes a file unneccesary long, the second just feels really ugly.

---

4. Anyway call it `CarFinderKey`

**Advantage** Easy to implement.

**Disadvantage** Adds in my opinion too much *fuzz* to `CarFinder`. Still unncessary pollutes the naming, just with a name that is not likely to clash.

---

What is the recommended guideline?

Comment: The essence of this question is too abstract and opinion-based for SO. You should better post this kind of questions in a site like SE Programmers (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I always use internal or private nested classes (what you call child class in 3.). The .NET framework itself uses this pattern a lot (even internally for C# syntactic sugar, yields, etc.). They also have a big advantage that you don't list: they can access private and protected members of the containing class.

Comment: Can you please give some details about the fields and operations of the "Key" class? If the operations can be abstracted to be used by all the entities in your system, you can just implement a system-wide EntityKey<EntityType> key class which will not cuase pollution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's opinion based. Anyway, I would:

1. try to make it a private nested class of `CarFinder`, which usually fails because the `Key` needs to be passed over to `CarManager`, you know what I mean. Public nested classes are discouraged.
2. I would put it into a sub-namespace called `Core`, a common name for internal stuff. For me, `Core` is "namespace internal" by naming convention.
3. The larger the project, the longer names you need. `CarFinderKey` is still a valid option.

I would never create additional assemblies just for this. It just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Thanks for your well explained answer. Is there a really clear reason why public nested classes are discouraged though?

Comment: There is an FxCop rule that hits this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx

Comment: @DirkBoer If you have a public nested class, and the only reason it is nested is to provide some semantic separation, then if you think about it, you are kind of using the "outer" class (the one you are nesting it inside of) as a namespace for the nested class.  In that case, I would consider it better practice to just use a namespace.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I don't mind the extra "fuzz" caused by CarFinderKey, and here is why:  Once worked on a very large project where we tried to use namespaces to disambiguate names.

So as you expand your system, you can very easily end up with 10 tabs open in your code editor, all named "Key.cs".  That was seriously not fun.

Comment: Totally agree with this. You never know when a project will grow or change, and utterly unambiguous names helps. It can also be good to try to avoid SQL keywords if there is a database involved.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same dilemma many times, and personally use (3) and a variation of (4).

(3): I have no problem with neither putting the nested class/struct within the same file (if it is small and really tied with the parent class), nor using a separate file within `partial ParentClass` declaration - the only drawback is that it gets one more level of indentation, but I can live with that. I also have no problem with violating FxCop rules or other recommendations - after all, they are just recommendations, not mandatory. But many people do have problems with all or some of these, so let move on.

(4): You already described the cons. What I'm going to share is how I do overcome them. Again, it's personal and one might or might not like it, but here it is.

First, let say we use a separate file for the key class and name the class `CarFinderKey`.

Then, **inside** the code file for the `CarFinder` class, we put the following line at the end of (or anywhere inside) the `using` section:

```
using Key = CarFinderKey;
```

This way, **only inside** the `CarFinder` class code file, anywhere `CarFinderKey` is needed, we can just refer to it simply as `Key`, what was the goal. At the same time we keep all the advantages and no clashes. Intellisence works w/o any problem. In VS2015, the lightbulb would even suggest to "simplify the name" for you anywhere it finds `CarFinderKey` inside that file.

Comment: Upvoted, but I prefer not to use aliases for things like this.  Aliasing for namespace disambiguation (`using _File = Pri.LongPath.File` in a lot of my file-system files) rather than name shortening.

Comment: @Corey Sure, and I do understand that not many would like it anyway. I look at this more like code unification rather than shortening. In my case I have a lot of similar related sets of classes like { entity, dto, repository etc.}  so I prefer treating them (in most of the cases) as a generic class arguments (although they are not), and usually create "standard" aliases `using TEntity = ...; using TDto = ...; using TRepository = ...`. But that's just a personal preference (as is the original question anyway :-))

Comment: I used to do so, but these days I restrict that to shortening extremely long common local classes or where I am using classes from libraries that mimic framework classes like the various System.IO replacements.  I just think it helps there to disambiguate.  I try to avoid having multiple classes in an assembly that have the same name in different contexts, it just leads to more confusion... and I have enough of that already :)

Answer (score 3):

Your decision should depend on your design. Is your Key class really a key only for CarFinders, or could it also be used to find motorcycles or houses or whatever.

One of the first rules the famous Gang of Four stipulated was "Design for change". If you really think that in the very near future your key could also be used to find houses or motorcycle, then it would not be a good idea to make your key class thus private that other could not use it.

Since you are speaking about private helper classes, I assume your key is only useful for CarFinders.

If that is the case and your design dictates that the Key is only useful for CarFinders, or maybe even: if it is designed such that it even isn't useful outside CarFinders the Key class ought to be part of the CarFinders class. Compare this to a simple integer that you would use in the CarFinders class, you would declare it private inside the CarFinders class wouldn't you?

Leaves you with the problem of one big file or a partial definition. From design point of view there is no difference. For the compiler there is also no difference. The only difference is for humans who have to read it. If you think that users of your class seldom have to read the definition of your key class, then it is better to define it in a separate file. However, if you regularly need to read the key class while reading the CarFinder class you should make access to the key class as easy as possible. If your development environment is fairly file oriented instead of class oriented, then I think that in that case the disadvantage of a large file is less than the disadvantage of having to switch between files.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the class and their "helpers" in their own namespace **MyNamespace.CarFinding**,

so that you have :

- *MyNamespace.CarFinding.CarFinder*
- *MyNamespace.CarFinding.Key*

and I will just put this namespace in a sub-folder of the project.

This will not block the internal helper class to be used elsewhere in the project, but from the parent namespace you could reference your helper as *CarFinding.Key*

Comment: This would mean that all classes that use `CarFinder` are polluted with a class named `Key` - that is exactly what I try to prevent.

Comment: Not if you always explicitly reference the classes with the namespace, like CarFinding.CarFinder and CarFinding.Key, without adding the using directive.

Comment: Or you could create a namespace just for the helpers, like CarFinding.Helpers.Key, so that you just pollute the namespace with the Helpers namespace, you just reference the class as Key in your CarFinder, and you use the full CarFinding.Helpers.Key if you want to use it outside.

Comment: I like fluent interfaces which gives me that ability to put all my helper classes in entirely different namespace the only time I see them is when the current class or method I'm working on has a reference to the extension methods found elsewhere in the project.  For example all classes may have a ToString() method but they don't have a ToXMLString() method.  I can simply create an extension method that is only for this or a certain set of classes.  Viola! No namespace pollution but help is there when you need it.